# Displaying alert many times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a java script for alerting message when form submitted. I am using same form at many place. Bellow are my js code,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var form = document.getElementById("form_demo-form");
    jQuery("#form_demo-form").submit(function(e){
    email = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)| 
            (".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9] 
            {1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

mb = /^((\+\d{1,3}(-|.| )?\(?\d\)?(-| |.)?\d{1,5})|(\(? 
         \d{2,6}\)?))(-|.| )?(\d{3,4})(-|.| )?(\d{4})(( x| 
         ext)\d{1,5}){0,1}$/;

   if( ((form.field_qh4icy4.value !="") &&
        (form.field_269dk2.value != "") && 
        (form.field_1bgl12.value != "") && 
        (email.test(form.field_29yf4d4.value)) && 
        (mb.test(form.field_6dask2.value)) && 
        (form.field_t6rya2.value != "") && 
        (form.field_9jv0r14.value != "")))
     {
        alert("Thank you for contacting us. We have received your 
        enquiry. One of our representatives will respond to you 
        within 24 hours");
        window.location.assign("/blog/thankyou"); 
    }
  else{
    e.preventDefault();
      }
   });
</script>
```

But alert message displayed two times rather than once.I need a help.Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I've retagged your question with more appropriate tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use e.preventDefault(); on submit click, I have corrected the code and paste it below. try this one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var form = document.getElementById("form_demo-form");
    jQuery("#form_demo-form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    email = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)| 
            (".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9] 
            {1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

mb = /^((\+\d{1,3}(-|.| )?\(?\d\)?(-| |.)?\d{1,5})|(\(? 
         \d{2,6}\)?))(-|.| )?(\d{3,4})(-|.| )?(\d{4})(( x| 
         ext)\d{1,5}){0,1}$/;

   if( ((form.field_qh4icy4.value !="") &&
        (form.field_269dk2.value != "") && 
        (form.field_1bgl12.value != "") && 
        (email.test(form.field_29yf4d4.value)) && 
        (mb.test(form.field_6dask2.value)) && 
        (form.field_t6rya2.value != "") && 
        (form.field_9jv0r14.value != "")))
     {
        alert("Thank you for contacting us. We have received your 
        enquiry. One of our representatives will respond to you 
        within 24 hours");
        window.location.assign("/blog/thankyou"); 
    }
  else{
    e.preventDefault();
      }
   });
</script>
```